# Get callback of Unity Input System UI Module

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

This is the Input System for UI in Unity

[image: input system UI module]

I am trying to catch the events as i would do for another `InputAction` :

```
void OnCancel(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
     //Do things
}
```

But i never get this callback. How can i use this module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Input System UI Input Module** is a bridge between the Inputsystem and the UI Input management, the callbacks are managed internally.

From the documentation page :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.InputSystemUIInputModule.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_UI_InputSystemUIInputModule_cancel

It is stated that:

> The events generated from this input will be received by UnityEngine.EventSystems.ICancelHandler.

If you implement the interface **ICancelHandler** on your **MonoBehaviour** and the respective **OnCancel** method, you should see the method getting called when your object is selected and a cancel action is triggered.

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour, ICancelHandler
{
    // Your script code.

    public void OnCancel(EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        // This is getting called when a Cancel event occurs.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The UI specific default actions come shipped together with the `DefaultInputActions` asset shipped with the package containing

[image]

Afaik you can attach listeners simply via e.g.

```
new DefaultInputActions().UI.OnCancel.performed += OnCancel;
```

If you are rather using your own custom Input Actions asset you need to also configure those in there.

You can select the `UI` action map and copy it (<kbd>CTRL C</kbd>) and then go into your custom Input Actions asset and paste it there into the actions maps (<kbd>CTRL V</kbd>).